# Cryptomatte is showing the same color for different materials?

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

I am using cryptomatte. That mostly works fine for me but I found it uncomfortable sometimes. As you all know, the pick color of Cryptomatte depends on the name of the material. The problem is that sometimes Cryptomatte gives the same color for materials with different names.

Please see the attached example:

[image]

I deliberately renamed the material to reproduce the extreme case. Notice that the pick colors of all six cubes in the Cryptomatte node are all white. This is on the easy side. Imagine a situation where you pick adjacent materials that are adjacent and have the same pick color in a much more complicated scene. You can change the name of the material to avoid this, but I think it's not a good idea to rename a material that's named according to the rules that make sense for any project.

[image]

**Q:** Is there any solution for this case? Has anyone else experienced this inconvenience?

---

**I've written more about thibsert's comments below.**
My viewer node's display channel option is set to "Color and Alpha" rather than "Alpha".
The new GIF below shows that.
In addition, it shows that the color of the cryptomatte pick color changes when the material is renamed.
A new color has appeared but still pick colors that have the same color in two adjacent cubes in the top right corner.
In particular, in my experience, the pick colors of background objects and small props were often displayed in the same color, which was inconvenient.

[image]

Comment: Please make sure your viewer Display Channel isn't set to "Alpha" but to "Color and Alpha".

Comment: @thibsert Of course thibsert.
My viewer node display is set to "Color and Alpha".
I have attached a new GIF at the bottom of the text to prove this, so please check it.